# Quería acceder al botón de un Fragment en Android Studio desde el Main, ¿sería posible?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment

lo que necesitaba era conseguir hacer uso del onRadioButtonClicked1 desde el xml de un Fragment.

Código del Fragment

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/p1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:text="PREGUNTA 1"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="60sp"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.4"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
 <RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="0.4">


    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/opcion1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/opcion2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/opcion3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
 </RadioGroup>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.6">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/respuesta1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="Respuesta1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/respuesta2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="Respuesta2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/respuesta1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/respuesta3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/respuesta2"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="Respuesta3" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.2">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/botonComprobarB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="Comprobar"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Código del Main

```
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private int puntos = 0;
    private boolean p1 = false;
    private boolean p2 = false;
    private boolean p3 = false;
    private boolean p4 = false;
    private boolean p5 = false;
    private boolean p6 = false;
    private boolean p7 = false;
    private boolean p8 = false;
    private boolean p9 = false;
    private boolean p10 = false;
    private boolean p11 = false;

    public boolean getP1() {
        return p1;
    }

    public void setP1(boolean p1) {
        this.p1 = p1;
    }

    public boolean getP2() {
        return p2;
    }

    public void setP2(boolean p2) {
        this.p2 = p2;
    }

    public boolean getP3() {
        return p3;
    }

    public void setP3(boolean p3) {
        this.p3 = p3;
    }

    public boolean getP4() {
        return p4;
    }

    public void setP4(boolean p4) {
        this.p4 = p4;
    }

    public boolean getP5() {
        return p5;
    }

    public void setP5(boolean p5) {
        this.p5 = p5;
    }

    public boolean getP6() {
        return p6;
    }

    public void setP6(boolean p6) {
        this.p6 = p6;
    }

    public boolean getP7() {
        return p7;
    }

   public void setP7(boolean p7) {
        this.p7 = p7;
    }

    public boolean getP8() {
        return p8;
    }

    public void setP8(boolean p8) {
        this.p8 = p8;
    }

    public boolean getP9() {
        return p9;
    }

    public void setP9(boolean p9) {
        this.p9 = p9;
    }

    public boolean getP10() {
        return p10;
    }

    public void setP10(boolean p10) {
        this.p10 = p10;
    }

    public boolean getP11() {
        return p11;
    }

    public void setP11(boolean p11) {
        this.p11 = p11;
    }

    public int getPuntos(){
        return puntos;
    }

    public void setPuntos(int puntos){
        this.puntos = puntos;
    }

    public void sumarPuntos(int puntos){
        this.puntos+=puntos;
    }
/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
 * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
 * may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Comprobando Puntos...", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, 
false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) 
 rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, 
  getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        Fragment tabFragment = null;

        switch (position){
            case 0:
                tabFragment = new TabAFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                tabFragment = new TabBFragment();
                break;
            case 2:
                tabFragment = new TabCFragment();
                break;
            case 3:
                tabFragment = new TabDFragment();
                break;
            case 4:
                tabFragment = new TabEFragment();
                break;
            case 5:
                tabFragment = new TabFFragment();
                break;
            case 6:
                tabFragment = new TabGFragment();
                break;
            case 7:
                tabFragment = new TabHFragment();
                break;
            case 8:
                tabFragment = new TabIFragment();
                break;
            case 9:
                tabFragment = new TabJFragment();
                break;
            case 10:
                tabFragment = new TabKFragment();
                break;
            case 11:
                tabFragment = new TabLFragment();
                break;
            case 12:
                tabFragment = new TabMFragment();
                break;
        }

        return tabFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 13;
    }
}

//Metodo para mostrar puntos.
public void mostrarPuntos(View view){
    Variables variables = (Variables)getApplicationContext();
    String puntos = Integer.toString(variables.getPuntos());
    TextView puntoTv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.puntosAcumulados);
    puntoTv.setText("PUNTOS: "+puntos);

}

//BORRAR CUANDO ACABE
public void pruebas(View view){

}


//Metodos para comprobar los Radio Button.
public void onRadioButtonClicked1(View view) {
    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
    Toast respuestaCorrecta = 
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"¡Respuesta 
Correcta!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    Toast respuestaIncorrecta = 
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"¡Respuesta 
  Incorrecta!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.opcion1:
            //Verdadera
            if (checked)
                if (getP1()==false){
                    sumarPuntos(9);
                    setP1(true);
                    respuestaCorrecta.show();
                }else {
                    Toast respuestaRepetida = 
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"NO ADMITIMOS RESPUESTAS DOS 
  VECES",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    respuestaRepetida.show();
                }

            break;
        case R.id.opcion2:
            if (checked)
                if (getP1()==false){
                    setP1(true);
                    respuestaIncorrecta.show();
                }else {
                    Toast respuestaRepetida = 
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"NO ADMITIMOS RESPUESTAS DOS 
 VECES",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    respuestaRepetida.show();
                }
                break;
        case R.id.opcion3:
            if (checked)
                if (getP1()==false){
                    setP1(true);
                    respuestaIncorrecta.show();
                }else {
                    Toast respuestaRepetida = 
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"NO ADMITIMOS RESPUESTAS DOS 
 VECES",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    respuestaRepetida.show();
                }
                break;
    }
}
```

Codigo del botón

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked1(View view) {
        // Is the button now checked?
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
        Toast respuestaCorrecta = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"¡Respuesta Correcta!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        Toast respuestaIncorrecta = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"¡Respuesta Incorrecta!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        // Check which radio button was clicked
        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.opcion1:
                //Verdadera
                if (checked)
                    if (getP1()==false){
                        sumarPuntos(9);
                        setP1(true);
                        respuestaCorrecta.show();
                    }else {
                        Toast respuestaRepetida = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"NO ADMITIMOS RESPUESTAS DOS VECES",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        respuestaRepetida.show();
                    }

                break;
            case R.id.opcion2:
                if (checked)
                    if (getP1()==false){
                        setP1(true);
                        respuestaIncorrecta.show();
                    }else {
                        Toast respuestaRepetida = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"NO ADMITIMOS RESPUESTAS DOS VECES",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        respuestaRepetida.show();
                    }
                    break;
            case R.id.opcion3:
                if (checked)
                    if (getP1()==false){
                        setP1(true);
                        respuestaIncorrecta.show();
                    }else {
                        Toast respuestaRepetida = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"NO ADMITIMOS RESPUESTAS DOS VECES",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        respuestaRepetida.show();
                    }
                    break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Deberías añadir un poco más de información para que la gente pueda ayudarte, las preguntas que son sólo código acaban siendo cerradas

Comment: ¿Pongo todo el código del main?

Comment: no hace falta poner todo el código, sino que expliques detalladamente el problema que tienes, que has probado, y pongas aquel código que pueda ayudar a resolver el problema. Saludos

Comment: Saludos @arturofb bienvenido a `stackoverflow`, podrías por favor explicar un poco mejor que necesitas hacer? y los métodos que has intentado para lograrlo, para poder comprender un poco mejor tu pregunta, gracias